How or where can I get a Linux driver for the Dell Latitude 5400 fingerprint scanner?
I have a Dell Latitude 5400 with a fingerprint scanner which I don't have drivers for. I'm running Debian 12 on Linux 6.1.0-25-amd64. I can't find anything on Dell's official driver download page for Ubuntu drivers; I also talked with a support agent who was very helpful but could not find anything on their end.
I've also ran sudo lshw and found nothing (although I don't entirely know what I'm looking for).
Is there anything else I can do?

Use lspci and lsusb to find out a line mentioning "fingerprint". Copy/paste it here by [edit]ing the question. That said, don't keep your hopes high. There are quite a few of this devices that simply don't have support for Linux. Yours is very likely one of those.

If it's important to you, a third-party reader might work: https://www.neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi?group=platforms_linux_android . That said, one study (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3671873) showed error rates for false positives as high as 28% -- i.e., more than 1/4 of random near matches would be accepted.

Yeah, there's nothing in lsusb nor lspci. I might look into third party readers.
Thank you so much for your help (:
